# Meaningfully compare target vs observed TPR & FPR

Tags: probability, classification, model-evaluation

Suppose I have a binary classifier $f$ which acts on an input $x$. Given a threshold $t$, the predicted binary output is defined as:
$$
\widehat{y} = \begin{cases}
    1, & f(x) \geq t \\
    0, & f(x) < t
\end{cases}
$$
I then compute the $TPR$ (true positive rate) and $FPR$ (false positive rate) metrics on the hold-out test set (call it $S_1$):

- $TPR_{S_1} = \Pr(\widehat{y} = 1 | y = 1, S_1)$
- $FPR_{S_1} = \Pr(\widehat{y} = 1 | y = 0, S_1)$

Next, say I deploy the classifier to production (i.e. acting on real-world data), and after two weeks I collect the results and have the data labelled (by a human, assume no errors in labelling). Call this data set $S_2$. I observe the following:

- total samples during this period = $|S_2|$ = $N$ negative + $P$ positive
- $TPR_{S_2} = \Pr(\widehat{y} = 1 | y = 1, S_2)$
- $FPR_{S_2} = \Pr(\widehat{y} = 1 | y = 0, S_2)$

---

My question is this:

> Under what conditions / assumptions I can **meaningfully** compare the **target TPR, FPR** (as computed on the hold-out set $S_1$) to the **observed TPR, FPR** (as computed on the production data set $S_2$)? Or, at the very least, is there a relation between TPR, FPR on $S_1$ and TPR, FPR on $S_2$, does it even make sense to compare them?

My intuition is that the input distributions in $S_1$ and $S_2$ should be similar, but I need some help formalizing this concept.

Any tips and literature suggestions are greatly appreciated!